# Using the apt package manager refuse an update for a specific package

Tags: package-management, apt, upgrade

I am attempting to upgrade a few packages using the apt package manager. However there is a specific package in the list that I don't want to upgrade. In fact I don't want anyone to ever upgrade it. Is there a way from forever blocking any specific packages?

In this case there's a grub update that I don't want to occur ever by myself or any other unix admins. Is this even possible? If so how do I go about doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the package “on hold”. You do that by issuing

```
echo 'your-package hold' | dpkg --set-selections
```

Use

```
dpkg --get-selections [package pattern]
```

to see what the current selections are.

Use

```
echo 'your-package install' | dpkg --set-selections
```

to make the package upgradeable again.

Comment: That works perfectly. FYI if you are using apt the solution is using a tool called apt-mark and the syntax is as follows:

apt-mark hold ^grub.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the package on hold at the dpkg level is one approach. Another one is to assign such a high priority to the installed package within apt that it is never upgraded. See man apt_preferences.

Answer (score 0):

With Aptitude, interactively: press `=` (or select “Hold” from the “Package” menu) on the package line. On the command line:

```
aptitude hold grub-pc
```

Since Debian wheezy, you can also use `apt-mark hold grub-pc` (thanks [Mark D](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36322/using-the-apt-package-manager-refuse-an-update-for-a-specific-package/36343#comment49267_36323)).